# How do I access a list of IP addresses that have been used to access my Twitter account?

Tags: security, twitter

My girlfriend discovered that her Twitter password had been changed.

We have changed the password, but is there a way to list the IP addresses that have been used to access the account?

Comment: You need to contact with the Twiter - they will be able to give you a listing of IP addresses that were used to access specific acount.

Comment: Yep. *Only* Twitter can help you.